# Ember+Mongoose doesn't return records

Tags: json, node.js, express, ember.js, mongoose

Well I'm having an issue with ember and the models,  because I want to return a JSON from a Mongoose API, using Express, the issue it's that the route return the json correctly, but when I try to catch it in the front end (Ember) it's returning like null.

In my Ember route I had the following:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){ //i'm getting params from the url as a paremeter
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({

      questions: this.store.find('examGroupQuestion/show-q', params.questionsGroup_id)
    });
  }
});
```

It's important that this route it's child from another one, next I show you the router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
 this.route('examGroupQuestion',function() {
   this.route('showQ',{
     path: 'showQ/:questionsGroup_id'
   });
 });
});
export default Router;
```

And finally this is my model:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({ 
/* the atributte array it's defined in a transform */
  description: attr('string'),
  matrix_eval: attr('array'),
  level: attr('string'),
  rows: attr('array'),
  randomize_row: attr('boolean'),
  columns: attr('array'),
  randomize_col: attr('boolean'),
});
```

Well having this, we are trying to pass the json from the route model to the template, but the record always show that it's null, like in the next image that we can see the REST Server response and the error:

[image: This is the error that Ember returns]

In the REST Server I had this route:

```
router.route('/examGroupQuestion/showQs/:qid').get(function(req,res){ questions_group.getQuestions(req,res, req.params.qid); });
```

and in the api I had the following:

```
module.exports.getQuestions = function(req,res,id){
  QuestionGroup.findById(id).exec(function(err, questiongroup){
    if(err)
    {
      res.send(err);
    }

    function done(result){
      res.json({questionsGroup:result});
    }

    var result = [];
    var l = questiongroup.questions.length;
    for(var j = 0; j < l; j++)
    {
      (function(j){
        Questions.findById(questiongroup.questions[j].id).exec(function(err, questions){
          if(err)
          {
            res.send(err);
          }
          result.push(questions);
          if(l === j+1)
          {
            done(result);
          }
        });
      })(j);
    }
  });
};
```

Does anyone know why it's this happening, any the help it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**findRecord (modelName, id, options) Promise**

This method returns a record for a given type and id combination. The `findRecord` method will always resolve its promise with the same object for a given type and id. The `findRecord` method will always return a promise that will be resolved with the record.

Change your route to

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('examGroupQuestion/show-q', params.questionsGroup_id);
  }
});
```

just make sure this is correct model 'examGroupQuestion/show-q'

If the record is not yet available, the store will ask the adapter's `find` method to find the necessary data. If the record is already present in the store, it depends on the reload behavior when the returned promise resolves.

Comment: It look's ok, but the function `findRecord` only get one record with an specific model, the thing it's that i'm returning an array of promises, and I need to fetch all of them because each promise came with questions data inside.

Comment: well you may use `query`, This method delegates a query to the adapter. This is the one place where adapter-level semantics are exposed to the application. example: store.query('person', { ids: [1, 2, 3] });